# Using jquery validate during form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I'm really new at this and I'm encountering an issue where the alert for a ddl is popping up, but in the background the form is still submitting with a blank from the value "" on the 'Select' option

The ddl:
            **Type**

My scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

function saveCallReport() {

```
        var selectedFranchises = "";
        var selectedGroups = "";
        var selectedContacts = "";
        var selectedTopics = "";

        var ID = $('#<%=txtID.ClientID %>').val();
        if (ID == '') ID = '0';

        var Created = $('#<%=txtCreated.ClientID %>').val();
        var Confidential = document.getElementById('<%=chkConfidential.ClientID %>').checked;
        var Description = $('#<%=txtDescription.ClientID %>').val();
        var Employee = $('#<%=ddlEmployee.ClientID %>').val();
        var Priority = $('#<%=ddlPriority.ClientID %>').val();
        var Type = $('#<%=ddlType.ClientID %>').val();

        // Get Selected Franchises
        var LstRight = document.getElementById("<%=lstSelectedFranchises.ClientID %>");
        for (i = 0; i < LstRight.length; i++) {
            selectedFranchises = selectedFranchises + LstRight.options[i].value + ',';
        }
        if (selectedFranchises == null)
            selectedFranchises = "";

        // Get Selected Groups
        LstRight = document.getElementById("<%=lstSelectedGroups.ClientID %>");
        for (i = 0; i < LstRight.length; i++) {
            selectedGroups = selectedGroups + LstRight.options[i].value + ',';
        }
        if (selectedGroups == null)
            selectedGroups = "";

        // Get Selected Contacts
        LstRight = document.getElementById("<%=lstSelectedContacts.ClientID %>");
        for (i = 0; i < LstRight.length; i++) {
            selectedContacts = selectedContacts + LstRight.options[i].value + ',';
        }
        if (selectedContacts == null)
            selectedContacts = "";

        // Get Selected Topics
        LstRight = document.getElementById("<%=lstSelectedTopics.ClientID %>");
        for (i = 0; i < LstRight.length; i++) {
            selectedTopics = selectedTopics + LstRight.options[i].value + ',';
        }
        if (selectedTopics == null)
            selectedTopics = "";

        var obj = {
            id: ID,
            created: Created,
            hqemployee: Employee,
            type: Type,
            priority: Priority,
            confidential: Confidential,
            description: Description,
            franchises: selectedFranchises,
            groups: selectedGroups,
            contacts: selectedContacts,
            topics: selectedTopics,
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/CallReportDetail.aspx/saveCallReport") %>',
            data: JSON.stringify(obj),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {

                $('#txtID').val(result.d);
                window.location.replace("/CallReports/Details?Id=" + result.d);

            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

                alert("There was a problem saving the Call Report: " + thrownError);

            }
        });

        return false;
    }

    var submit = 0;
    function CheckDouble() {
        if (++submit > 1) {
            alert('Saving...');
            return false;
        }
    }

    $(function formValid() {
        $("[id*=btnSave]").click(function() {
            var ddlType = $("[id*=ddlType]");
            if (ddlType.val() == "") {
                alert("Please select a type!");
                return false;
            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

My submit button:

```
                <td style="padding-left: 720px;">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnSave" Type="submit" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClientClick="CheckDouble(); return saveCallReport();" UseSubmitBehavior="false" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-sm"/>
            </td>
```

Can anybody tell me where I may be going wrong? I had a notion that I need a submitHandler, but don't have a clue how to write that into this code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok there's a few issues here.

1. You should avoid adding OnClientClick and JQuery .click() events on the same button. It's just bad style, and a bit confusing.
2. You're submitting the data via JQuery ajax, so there's no need for a LinkButton. Just use a normal html button.
3. Your saveCallReport() function handles the success and failure outcomes all by itself, there's no need to return anything.
4. The CheckDouble() method will increment the submit value even if the validation fails, so then a subsequent click on the button after you select from the ddl will alert the Saving... message, which is not the intended behavior. You should just add/remove a disabled attribute on the button while it's submitting.

So anyway, here's what I would suggest. The html button:

```
<button id="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Save</button>
```

Wire up the button:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btnSave').click(function () {

        var ddlType = $("#ddlType");
        if (ddlType.val() == "") {
            alert("Please select a type!");
            return false;
        }

        $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        saveCallReport();
        $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
    });
});
```